# Task Parallel System.NullReferenceException or System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I am getting error randomly (mostly it'll work perfectly but sometimes these errors will come) in any of my methods. The errors are:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   might not execute.

```
  private void LoadAllComboxData()
    {
        var t1 = new Task(() => LoadInCombobox1());
        t1.Start();
                        up to

        var t5 = new Task(() => LoadInCombobox5());
        t5.Start();
    }

private void LoadInCombobox1()
{
 this.LoadInCombobox1TableAdapter.Fill(this.eADBDataSet.LoadInCombobox1);
}
                   up to 

private void LoadInCombobox5()
{
 this.LoadInCombobox5TableAdapter.Fill(this.eADBDataSet.LoadInCombobox5);
}
```

What I'm planning to accomplish is to simultaneously retrieve corresponding data from the database and load it to its corresponding Combobox.

Comment: using sql express?

Comment: It would appear that things you're sharing across multiple threads (`eADBDataSet` being the obvious one) are not thread safe.

Comment: @BugFinder SQL Server Standard Edition

Comment: u need to execute the update binding of combobox  in dispatcher

Comment: It seems like the setter of `eADBDataSet.LoadInCombobox1` re-creates and fills an internal collection member. When you try to access it from one thread while another one modifies it then you get such errors. Could you post the implementation of one of the LoadInCombobox properties? And if it's not there, it's very likely in the `.Fill`-Method of the adapter.

Comment: @Stephan properties are autogenerated. All five tables are in eADBDataSet.

Comment: @Stephan        public virtual int Fill(EADBDataSet.LoadInCombobox1DataTable dataTable) {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
            if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true)) {
                dataTable.Clear();
            }
            int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return returnValue;
        }